# Change GeoPandas geometry from GeometryCollection to MultiPolygon

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a GeoPandas dataframe where the features have a Geometry type of 'GeometryCollection'.

It looks like each feature is in fact just a simple polygon, so I'd like to convert the GeometryCollection geometries to Polygon or MultiPolygon.

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the individual geometries in the collection with `.geoms`. List them, explode to rows:

```
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd

#Create a test df
poly1 = shapely.MultiPolygon([(((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)), [((0.1,0.1), (0.1,0.2), (0.2,0.2), (0.2,0.1))])])
poly2 = shapely.MultiPolygon([(((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)), [((0.1,0.1), (0.1,0.2), (0.2,0.2), (0.2,0.1))])])
poly3 = shapely.MultiPolygon([(((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)), [((0.1,0.1), (0.1,0.2), (0.2,0.2), (0.2,0.1))])])
gc1 = shapely.GeometryCollection([poly1, poly2])
gc2 = shapely.GeometryCollection([poly2, poly3])
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[gc1, gc2])
# df.geometry
# 0    GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00000 0....
# 1    GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00000 0....

#Create a list of all geometries in each collection
df["geometries"] = df.apply(lambda x: [g for g in x.geometry.geoms], axis=1)
# df
#                                             geometry                                         geometries
# 0  GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00000 0....  [MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0), (0....
# 1  GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00000 0....  [MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0), (0....

#Explode each list to rows, one row for each geometry in the list.
#  Then drop the geometry column with the geometrycollections, set the geometry to the exploded ones,
#    and rename it to geometry
df = df.explode(column="geometries").drop(columns="geometry").set_geometry("geometries").rename_geometry("geometry")

# df
#                                            geometry
# 0  MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1.000...
# 0  MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1.000...
# 1  MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1.000...
# 1  MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1.000...
```

Answer (score 2):

I worked out an answer after I posted this which similarly to the answer shared by BERA uses explode.

`gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.explode()[0:].values`

The original GeometryCollection gets converted into MultiPolygon (since each geometry collection only had a single multipolygon in it).

Based on the info given in this GeoPandas [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1665)

Comment: Alot simpler than mine, nice!